# How to mark duplicate rows with the index of the first occurrence in Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a script that finds duplicate rows in a spreadsheet. I'm using the **Pandas** library. This is the initial dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'title': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'val1': [1.1, 1.1, 2.1, 8.8, 1.1, 1.1, 8.8, 8.8],
                   'val2': [2.2, 3.3, 5.5, 6.2, 2.2, 3.3, 6.2, 6.2],
                   'val3': [3.4, 4.4, 5.5, 8.4, 0.5, 3.4, 1.9, 3.7]
                   })

print(df)

title  val1     val2     val3
 1      1.1      2.2      3.4
 2      1.1      3.3      4.4
 3      2.1      5.5      5.5
 4      8.8      6.2      8.4
 5      1.1      2.2      0.5 
 6      1.1      3.3      3.4
 7      8.8      6.2      1.9
 8      8.8      6.2      3.7
```

I have found all duplicate rows using the **duplicated** method based on the indicated columns and marked them by adding a new column e.g.

```py
df['duplicate'] = df.duplicated(keep=False, subset=['val1', 'val2'])

print(df)

title  val1     val2     duplicated
 1      1.1      2.2        true
 2      1.1      3.3        true
 3      2.1      5.5        false
 4      8.8      6.2        true
 5      1.1      2.2        true
 6      1.1      3.3        true
 7      8.8      6.2        true
 8      8.8      6.2        true
```

In the last step, I would like to mark all duplicate rows by adding information with the title of the first occurrence. This way I want to make it easier to sort and group them later. This is what the result would look like:

```
title  val1     val2     first_occurence
 1      1.1      2.2         true
 2      1.1      3.3         true 
 3      2.1      5.5         false
 4      8.8      6.2         true
 5      1.1      2.2         title1
 6      1.1      3.3         title2
 7      8.8      6.2         title4
 8      8.8      6.2         title4
```

I tried to find a similar topic, but was unsuccessful. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two variants of [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) (with and without `keep=False`) and a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
cols = ['val1', 'val2']

# duplicates, except first
m1 = df.duplicated(cols)
# duplicates including first
m2 = df.duplicated(cols, keep=False)

df['first_occurrence'] = (
 df[cols].merge(df.loc[~m1, cols+['title']],
          how='left')['title']
   .astype(str).radd('title')
   .where(m1, m2)
)
```

Output:

```
   title  val1  val2  val3 first_occurrence
0      1   1.1   2.2   3.4             True
1      2   1.1   3.3   4.4             True
2      3   2.1   5.5   5.5            False
3      4   8.8   6.2   8.4             True
4      5   1.1   2.2   0.5           title1
5      6   1.1   3.3   3.4           title2
6      7   8.8   6.2   1.9           title4
7      8   8.8   6.2   3.7           title4
```

Comment: Would the rule be the same if I wanted to compare more columns? val4, val5 etc.

Comment: @nsog8sm43x I see no reason why not, the logic should be the same. Give it a try and let me know ;)

Comment: It works. Even if I add more conditions. Thank you! :)

Comment: coming back to this - how might you accomplish the same thing without the True/False values also remaining? (i.e. just keeping the title1, title2, etc.)

Would it also be possible to simply reference the first_occurrence index rather than a column value?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do in Pandas. That's a possible solution:

1. Get a list of duplicate rows
2. Iterate this list and generate a new row with a new column like "duplicate_index" and insert in this column the title number of the first equal row for each duplicated rows
3. Insert all rows (original with empty value in "duplicate_index") in a new df
4. Save the new df

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to Rexovas question in the comments. It could also be used for the original question. It is more neat and faster.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Mark duplicates with first occurrence index
df['IsDuplicate'] = df.duplicated(keep='first')
df['FirstOccurrence'] = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).ngroup()

# Display the modified DataFrame
print(df)
```